# passing data between pages correctly

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have been trying to seperate a single WP7 app page into two seperate pages so that I can keep the functionality in one page and the view in the other. Basically I am creating a tabbed webbrowser where I have different tabs that may be viewed upon the users request, and only the currently clicked tab is the one that is displayed in the view. So far I have a solution where this works in one page, but I would like to seperate this into a TabsPage (which would control the tab instances) and a MainPage (which would present the user with the currently selected tab for display). I am not sure of how to seperate these two pages correctly so that I can accomplish this functionality. What I have is as follows (which works thus far)

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox x:Name="UrlTextBox" KeyDown="UrlTextBox_KeyDown" InputScope="url"/>
    <Grid x:Name="BrowserHost" Grid.Row="1" />
    <!--<my:FullWebBrowser Name="TheBrowser" Grid.Row="1"/>-->

</Grid>

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="Tabs" IconUri="/Images/appbar.tab.rest.png" Text="tabs" Click="TabsPage_Click"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar.next.rest.png" IsEnabled="True" Text="forward" x:Name="ForwardBtn" Click="ForwardBtn_Click"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="1" Click="TabMenuItem_Click" />
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="2" Click="TabMenuItem_Click" />
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="3" Click="TabMenuItem_Click" />
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="4" Click="TabMenuItem_Click" />
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private const int NumTabs = 4;
    private int currentIndex;

    private string[] urls = new string[NumTabs]; 
    ////private WebBrowser[] browsers = new WebBrowser[NumTabs]; 
    private FullWebBrowser[] browsers = new FullWebBrowser[NumTabs];

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ShowTab(0); 
    }

    //protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    //}

    private void ShowTab(int index)
    {
        this.currentIndex = index;

        UrlTextBox.Text = this.urls[this.currentIndex] ?? "";

        if (this.browsers[this.currentIndex] == null)
        {
            //WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser(); 
            FullWebBrowser browser = new FullWebBrowser();

            this.browsers[this.currentIndex] = browser;

            BrowserHost.Children.Add(browser);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < NumTabs; i++)
        {
            if (this.browsers[i] != null)
            {
                this.browsers[i].Visibility = i == this.currentIndex ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }

    private void UrlTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            Uri url;

            //string _url;

            if (Uri.TryCreate(UrlTextBox.Text, UriKind.Absolute, out url))
            {
                this.urls[this.currentIndex] = UrlTextBox.Text;
                //_url = url.ToString();

                string _url = url.ToString();

                //this.browsers[this.currentIndex].Navigate(url); 
                this.browsers[this.currentIndex].Navigate(_url);
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid url");
        }
    }

    private void TabMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = Int32.Parse(((ApplicationBarMenuItem)sender).Text) - 1;
        ShowTab(index);
    }

    //**********************************************************************

    private void TabsPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/TabsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Note: I am using a webbrowser control named TheWebBrowser.
Any help with this on how to correctly seperate the MainPage into a TabsPage as well would be greatly appreciated! I have been working on this for a while and cannot seem to be able to pass the data properly between the pages (namedly the searchbar and the current webbrowser instance to be viewed on MainPage).

Answer (score 1):

Passing the values between Pages and still adhering to proper WP7 design can be accomplished by adding a save point in the App.xaml.cs file and then you can access the information using

```
(App.Current as App).SomeField
```

Now I have no experience with the webbrowser control you are using, but I am assuming that you can use the MVVM pattern to separate the data from the view. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286405%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) is a good example. Using MVVM will also allow you to [better support tombstoning](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/10/a-windows-phone-7-1-mango-mvvm-tombstoning-example/) with your application. Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: thanks @singelabs, could you show me how that might be used, I have never used App.Current as App before? Also, would there be an easier way just by passing data via querystring between the two pages to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I would just use Caliburn Micro to pass data between pages/screens. http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/ It has also a good documentation for you to begin with learning how to pass datas properly rather than doing (App.Current as App).SomeField.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, [this can be helpful](http://www.geekchamp.com/marketplace/components/smartnavigation).

EDIT: I mean, you can use [this component](https://smartnavigation.codeplex.com/), which is available via Nuget as

```
Install-Package SmartNavigation.
```

Probably its a bit raw, but totally worth to take a glance.

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Roger-roger :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it when I want to share data across pages for example. Define your property in App.xaml.cs (don't forget to init wherever you need to):

```
public List<Contact> Contacts
{
    get
    {
        return _contacts;
    }
}
```

Now in the pages you want to use this data, define it like so:

```
private List<Contact> Contacts
{
    get
    {
        return (App.Current as App).Contacts;
    }
}
```